# Neo4j - get shortest path between a specific node with id to a node with a label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find the closest node with a specific label to a node which i have his id.

```
MATCH (object{id:'1489751911095'}), (apiUser:ApiUser) ,
 p = allShortestPaths((object) - [*] - (apiUser))  return p limit 1
```

For some reason, it doesn't stops in the first encounter of the node apiUser:ApiUser, but is continuing further on.

Answer (score 1):

The [`allShortestPaths`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#_all_shortest_paths) feature enumerates all shortest paths between two nodes. So, for your query, it takes all possible pairs of `object` and `apiUser` nodes and enumerates all shortest paths between each pair. So how do we stop that from happening?

First, you might want to simplify your original query like this:

```
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((object {id:'1489751911095'})-[*]-(apiUser:ApiUser))
RETURN p
LIMIT 1
```

Second, if you only need one path, why not use the [`shortestPath`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#_single_shortest_path_with_predicates) feature?

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((object {id:'1489751911095'})-[*]-(apiUser:ApiUser))
RETURN p
LIMIT 1
```

This will still calculate a shortest path for each `apiUser`, so you'd want to order the results based on the length of the path:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((object {id:'1489751911095'})-[*]-(apiUser:ApiUser))
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This is not the most efficient solution, as Neo4j will still calculate the shortest path for each `apiUser` - whether the solution is applicable to your use case depends on the number of `apiUser`s in your database.

Answer (score 0):

When matching from a single node, a variable-length match with LIMIT 1 should work:

```
MATCH (object{id:'1489751911095'})-[*]-(p:ApiUser)
RETURN p limit 1
```

It's recommended to have a label in your match when looking up a node by property, and an index or unique constraint on the label+property so it's a fast match.

If you are unsure if there will be a node of that type close by, you may want to add an upper bound to your variable length match.